# Any closed form for the integral

Tags: integration

Using Maple, I can evaluate the integral below. Given $K > \theta$:

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty }{\left(1- {\rm e}^{-x}\right)^{K} \over
x^{\theta+1}}\,{\rm d}x\,,
\quad \mbox{where}\quad K > \theta > 1.
$$

Is there any closed form or approximation for the above integral ?.

Comment: What is the answer of the evaluation?

Comment: If $K, \theta$ are integers, you can represent the integral as a finite sum as in [this posting](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863895/how-to-evaluate-integral-int-0-infty-left-frac1-e-xx-rightn-dx/863926#863926).

Comment: K is integer, but $\theta$ could be integer or  positive number. However, I tried using binomial expansion. The expression becomes more complecated. I would like to know if there is a simple tractable expression for the integral.

Answer (score 2):

Although I have not made a rigorous computation, both heuristics and numerical computation suggest that the following expression

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(1-e^{-x})^K}{x^{\theta+1}} \, dx
&= \Gamma(-\theta) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{K}{n} (-1)^{n}n^{\theta} \\
&= \frac{\pi}{\Gamma(\theta+1)\sin(\pi\theta)} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{K}{n} (-1)^{n-1}n^{\theta}
\end{align*}

is true for any $0 < \Re(\theta) < K$. Here, it is not hard to check that poles of $\Gamma(-\theta)$ between $0$ and $K$ are cancelled by the summation part.

In particular, if $K \geq 1$ is integer then this reduces to a finite sum since $\binom{K}{n} = 0$ for $n > K$. However, I am not sure if this falls within the range of 'simple tractable expression'.

---

*Proof of the identity above.* By the principle of analytic continuation, we may prove the identity only when $0 < \theta < 1$. We find that

> **Lemma.** For $-1 < \alpha < 0$ and $s > 0$, we have
>   $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\alpha-1}(e^{-sx} - 1) \, dx = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{s^\alpha}. $$

The proof is straightforward from integration by parts:

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\alpha-1}(e^{-sx} - 1) \, dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{\alpha}}{\alpha} \cdot s e^{-sx} \, dx = \frac{s}{\alpha} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{s^{\alpha+1}} = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{s^{\alpha}}.$$

Now using this lemma, for $0 < \theta < 1$ we find that

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(1-e^{-x})^K}{x^{\theta+1}} \, dx
&\stackrel{(1)}{=} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(1-e^{-x})^K - (1-1)^K}{x^{\theta+1}} \, dx \\
&\stackrel{(2)}{=} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{-\theta-1} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{K}{n}(-1)^n(e^{-nx} - 1) \, dx \\
&\stackrel{(3)}{=} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{K}{n}(-1)^n \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{-\theta-1} (e^{-nx} - 1) \, dx \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{K}{n}(-1)^n \frac{\Gamma(-\theta)}{n^{-\theta}}.
\end{align*}

Here is a bit of explanation for each step:

$\text{(1)}$ : Since $K$ is positive, $(1 - 1)^K = 0^K = 0$ and subtracting this term causes no harm.

$\text{(2)}$ : We applied the generalized binomial theorem to expand both $(1 - e^{-x})^K$ and $(1 - 1)^K$. Also the term for $n = 0$ cancels out.

$\text{(3)}$ : I utilized Fubini's theorem. The estimation $(-1)^n \binom{K}{n} \sim C n^{-(K+1)}$ as $n \to \infty$ for some constant $C$ is useful when establishing the applicability of Fubini's theorem in this case.

The proof can be carried out without aid of analytic continuation, though it requires a more delicate control of integral because we have to cancel out higher order singularities.

Comment: This is very interesting and ... a very elegant solution, for sure. I played a little with it. Thanks for posting such an answer; it has been very inspiring to me. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, Lee. 
Can you please tell me, how you obtained the right hand side and the infinite summation?. I  have no clue yet.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks Lee. I'm very impressed by you answers. I want to ask you if there is a proof for K is integer for all $\theta < K$, where $\theta$ is real and positive ?

Comment: @YazanHusseinAl-Badarneh, This proof equally applies to the case where $K$ is an integer. (In fact, the proof simplifies a bit as you do not need to deal with infinite sums.)

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer.*

Very interested by Sangchul Lee approach and solution, I played with $$I_K=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(1-e^{-x})^K}{x^{\theta+1}} \, dx$$ assuming $K$ to be a positive integer and $1<\theta < K$. Using a CAS, the following results were obtained $$I_1=-\Gamma (-\theta )\qquad , \qquad I_2=\left(2^{\theta }-2\right) \Gamma (-\theta )$$ For $K>2$ writing $$J_K=\frac{\sin (\pi  \theta )\,\Gamma (\theta +1)}{\pi }\,I_K$$ $$J_3=3-3\ 2^{\theta }+3^{\theta }$$ $$J_4=4-6\ 2^{\theta }+4\ 3^{\theta }-4^{\theta }$$ $$J_5=5-10\ 2^{\theta }+10\ 3^{\theta }-5\ 4^{\theta }+5^{\theta }$$ $$J_6=6-15\ 2^{\theta }+20\ 3^{\theta }-15\ 4^{\theta }+6\ 5^{\theta }-6^{\theta }$$ $$J_7=7-21\ 2^{\theta }+35\ 3^{\theta }-35\ 4^{\theta }+21\ 5^{\theta }-7\ 6^{\theta
   }+7^{\theta }$$ $$J_8=8-28\ 2^{\theta }+56\ 3^{\theta }-70\ 4^{\theta }+56\ 5^{\theta }-28\ 6^{\theta
   }+8\ 7^{\theta
   }- 8^{\theta
   }$$ in which some clear patterns seem to appear (triangular numbers for $2^\theta$, tetrahedral  numbers for $3^\theta$, $\cdots$).